# Copy Data Activity - sudden behavior change

Tags: excel, mapping, azure-data-factory

We have a pipeline that copies data from Excel file located on Azure File Share to Azure SQL database.
e use explicit mapping in order to make it dynamical:

```
{"type": "TabularTranslator", "mappings":
[{"source":{"name":"Prop_0"},"sink":{"name":"Var1"}},
{"source":{"name":"Prop_1"},"sink":{"name":"Var2"}},
{"source":{"name":"Prop_2"},"sink":{"name":"Var3"}},
{"source":{"name":"AuditId"},"sink":{"name":"AuditId"}}]}
```

The `Prop_0` , `Prop_2` .. - columns from excel file, and  `AuditId`  is an additional column that we add in the pipeline.

The `Prop_2`  column can contain empty values.

Example of excel:

[image]

Until yesterday all worked fine, but now we receive an error:

```
ErrorCode=MappingColumnNameNotFoundInSourceFile,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Column 'Prop_1' specified in column mapping cannot be found in 'some_file.xlsx' source file.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'
```

It is quite strange because we haven't made any changes in ADF or in excel templates.

I played a bit with mapping and it seems that ADF only recognizes the first column in excel file, however if I add a second column( that has similar values in terms of type) to mapping it throws the same error.

It seems to me that there is some changes in ADF engine itself. Can it be the case ?

Answer (score 0):

My Understanding is that there might not have been changes in the Azure Data Factory itself that caused this issue.

The error message indicates that the column specified in the mapping, such as "Prop_1," cannot be found in the source file "some_file.xlsx."

This Could be that there might be an issue with the source file or the way it is being accessed.

Some times In the azure file share there could be a issue like replace or overwrite files if already exists I suggest Double-check that the Excel file "some_file.xlsx" exists in the specified location on the Azure File Share.

Ensure that the column name "Prop_1" is present in the file.

[image]
Also Check if the file format is changed and  Make sure that the file path specified in the pipeline is correct.

before you publish the changes and trigger the pipeline it is better check the data preview at the source in ADF

And you can import the schema and check for the column mapping.

As you said the pipeline ran good before the error occured it would be better if you can once give a retry to see if the pipeline runs fine back again.

I have tried with some sample data at my end using the ADFS(Azure datalake File share).
[image]
Make sure you have a constributor role for the File share.
[image]
Source:

[image]

Sink:

[image]

Column mapping:
[image]

[image]

Comment: We use dynamic mapping because we have different excel files. That is why we are using "Prop_..." column names to reference columns from the source Excel file.

Also I've tried to reference source columns via column number ({ "ordinal": "1" }), but because I have additional column it seems that it is impossible. You can try - disable headers in the source dataset , then add additional column to source ( let say AuditId) with some custom value, and in Mapping Import schemas.  I will appreciate if you share your results.